# After adding the pop-up menu, the rest of the content disappear and the overflow-x:hidden does not work

Tags: css

After adding the pop-up menu, the content inside "main" disappear and the `overflow-x:hidden` of the body does not work. Does anyone know why?

```js
const slide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu div");
  //Toggle Menu
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menupop");
  })
}
slide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: calc(16px + 0.25vw);
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: 'Antic Slab', serif;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: pink;
}

#rose {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

#rose-img {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color: rgb(134, 184, 204);
}

#tree {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

#about-us {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#contact-us {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background-color: orange;
}

.burger {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.line1,
.line2,
.line3 {
  flex: 1 1 1;
  width: 80%;
  height: 5%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px grey;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.a {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.b {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 249, 250, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Italianno', cursive;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(91, 126, 172, 0.5);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.menupop {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.menupop div {
  animation-name: menuFade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(245, 249, 250, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.menu div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes menuFade {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  .burger {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Flower</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tree</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="first"><a href="#">Flower</a></div>
    <div class="second"><a href="#">Tree</a></div>
    <div class="third"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <header id="jumbotron">

    </header>
    <section id="rose">

    </section>
    <section id="rose-img">

    </section>
    <section id="tree">
      <div class="privacy">

      </div>
      <div class="hedge">

      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="about-us">

    </section>
    <section id="contact-us">

    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Try removing `position:absolute;` from `.menu{}`

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, remove `overflow: scroll;`.

This should prevent your side menu from staying outside of your viewport width, because with `overflow: scroll;`, you're allowing the browser to have your side menu out of view, making it only reachable via scrolling.

I'd also like to add that your side menu transition is too long.
If you think about it from a user experience, a user might think that your site is slow.
I've shortened the `transition` to 200ms and removed the `animation-duration` and `animation-delay`. It'll seem more responsive to users now.

**EDIT:** Also, is anyone else finding it weird how when you use "Run Snippet" on Stackoverflow, use Full Page view, then try to shrink it down to mobile width, the media queries aren't working properly? It works fine when I run the code in VSCode and launch a Live Server, but for some reason, Stackoverflow's Run Snippet is being buggy...

**EDIT 2:** I've added content to each of your `div` tags and `section` tags. So the reason why you couldn't see any content under the `main` tag was because the height of all of your containers (`div`, `section`, `main`, and `header` tags) is, by default, `auto`. If `height` is `auto`, then the container will shrink or grow based on the content inside of the container. In your case, you had NO content in ANY of your containers, hence why all of your containers weren't visible, they were essentially at 0px height.

Now that I've added content, you can see your containers.

```js
const slide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu div");
  //Toggle Menu
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menupop");
  })
}
slide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: calc(16px + 0.25vw);
  font-family: 'Antic Slab', serif;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: pink;
}

#rose {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

#rose-img {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color: rgb(134, 184, 204);
}

#tree {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

#about-us {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

#contact-us {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background-color: orange;
}

.burger {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.line1,
.line2,
.line3 {
  flex: 1 1 1;
  width: 80%;
  height: 5%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px grey;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.a {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.b {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 249, 250, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Italianno', cursive;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(91, 126, 172, 0.5);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
}

.menupop {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.menupop div {
  animation-name: menuFade;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(245, 249, 250, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.menu div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes menuFade {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  .burger {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Flower</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tree</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="first"><a href="#">Flower</a></div>
    <div class="second"><a href="#">Tree</a></div>
    <div class="third"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <header id="jumbotron">
      This is a header with ID "jumbotron".
    </header>
    <section id="rose">
      This is a section with ID "rose".
    </section>
    <section id="rose-img">
      this is a section with ID "rose-img".
    </section>
    <section id="tree">
      <div class="privacy">
        This is a div with class "privacy".
      </div>
      <div class="hedge">
        This is a div with class "hedge".
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="about-us">
      This is a section with ID "about-us".
    </section>
    <section id="contact-us">
            This is a section with ID "contact-us".
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does solved the side menu exposure problem. But the content within "main" is still no where to be found.

Comment: Hey! Looking at your code, you don't actually have any content under `main`. You just have empty elements with IDs/classes on them. When you have no content under these elements (and their height isn't defined), the height is automatically set to `auto`, making the elements shrink in size. They're basically 0px in height right now, which is why you can't see them. 

If you want to double-check, open up your HTML File in your browser, then inspect it. The elements are all stacked into a 1px line basically.

If this answers your question, please mark it as Answered. :D

Comment: Hi Kvncnls, thank you. But I did declare the min-height of body and using grid template rows n column to set the main div's width n height in percentage relative to the body size.

Comment: min-height of the body doesn't affect the height of any of the divs. If you give the `body` element a height, it just changes the `body`'s height, not any of the other elements inside of it. By default, `div` elements have `height: auto;`. Auto causes them to shrink or grow according to their content. If your `div` elements have no content, they will essentially have no height. If this answered your question, please mark it as Answered on my post. Thank you! :)

Comment: I've added an edit to my post. If this answers your question, please mark your question as Answered on my post.